# windows docker image with .net 4.8.4190.0 version

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to remediate CVE-2020-1147 in one of my docker images. Right now I have  `\WindowsMicrosoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll` version `4.8.3761.0` on a container image and trying to get 4.8.4190.0 for this CVE fix

I am pulling windows:servercore:1809 image and installing .net with offline installer but it never gets installed. Any suggestions on how to install/upgrade .net to 4.8.4190.0 version